# I am retreiving data from firebase and the recyclerview is showing it out of order

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase. All the data comes up correctly but it is out of order and I can not figure out why? The data should be read from beginning to end:

[image]

```
  val publicFeedMap = HashMap<String, Feed>()

    private  fun refreshRecyclerViewMessages(){

        adapter.clear()
        publicFeedMap.values.forEach{
            adapter.add(PublicFeedItem(it))
        }
    }

    private fun fetchPublicFeed(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PublicFeed")

        ref.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener{

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                p0.children.forEach {
                    val feedItem = p0.getValue(Feed::class.java) ?: return

                    publicFeedMap[p0.key!!] = feedItem
                    refreshRecyclerViewMessages()

                }

            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            }
        })
    }
```

[the data should be sorted from beginning to end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhBth.png)

Comment: You haven't provided your data, or what your expected output would be, so its hard to tell what a "correct" order would be.  But, you're not actually making any calls that would order your query (e.g. `orderByChild` or `orderByKey` etc...)  See [the documentation about sorting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data)

Answer (score 0):

you have to order the data by adding:
orderByKey or orderByChild it would be better if you provide the data you want to use and how you want to order it

Check this:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-by-keys-and-values/

Check this also:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Also use a LinkedHashMap. Regular HashMap won’t preserve the order.